# Adding tables to the WordPress database. Any concerns?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Is there any reason not to add a few tables to the WordPress database? I'm not too familiar with WordPress and wouldn't want all that data to get flattened if WordPress was updated or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tables to your database without any issue. WordPress will leave any custom tables untouched with updates.

I would ask yourself if the new table is really necessary. For example. If the new data really should just be a WordPress custom post type and stored in wp_posts. Or maybe stored in the meta tables.